# Retrieved from Python interact Widget values

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I have a function to plot data from differents countries. 
I use *interact* from *ipywidgets* to change  interactively the countries values

```
getter=interact(plotcountries,
         ...
        countries=widgets.SelectMultiple(
             options=["Belgium","France","Germany","Italy","Portugal","Spain"*emphasized text*],
             value=["France","Italy","Spain"],
             rows=10,
             description='Countries',
             disabled=False)
```

I would like to get the values of widgets.SelectMultiple when it changes, to be able to put it inside a variable.
How I can proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
getinteract.widget.kwargs.get("countries")
```

but obviously in a cell after the Dropdown